# Angular & RxJS - Seeking suggestions on the best practices & code refactor

Tags: angular, performance, rxjs, refactoring, code-readability

I created [a mini app which shows the `Continent` & the `Country` selections.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hvcdxw)
just to practice RxJS concepts.
(You can checkout to **ng-conf/learn-rxjs-01** branch on https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hvcdxw to experience the app).

[image]
[image]
[image]

I believe that I refactored the entire app to its best. But I still want to know **if there is anything that I could enhance in the app [`index.html`, `AppComponent - View & Model`, `models.ts` files] to provide an optimal app performance & developer experience?**

Comment: Query extension - https://stackoverflow.com/q/77035091/19132064

Comment: You didn't unsubscribe, you used tap where an higher order operator like switchMap should be used