# `_http.get().pipe(publishReplay(), refCount())` behavior differs - if returned from a getterMethod() and - if declared as a property$

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I created [a mini app which shows the `Continent` & the `Country` selections](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hvcdxw)

> You can checkout to **`ng-conf/learn-rxjs-01`** branch on
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hvcdxw to view the app
> components

In the **`app.component.ts`** file

**if API call is returned from an `observable property` - *the call is triggered only once* - for each & every CONTINENT dropdown select**

```
fetchCountryByContinent$ = this._http.get<ContinentCountry[]>(this.countriesUrl).pipe(publishReplay(), refCount())
```

[image: API call is returned from an observable property - the call is triggered only once]
[image: API call is returned from an observable property - the call is triggered only once]

**if API call is returned from a `getter method` - *Call is triggered for each & every CONTINENT dropdown select***

```
get fetchCountryByContinent$() {
    return this._http.get<ContinentCountry[]>(this.countriesUrl).pipe(publishReplay(), refCount());
}
```

[image: API call is returned from a getter method - Call is triggered for each & every CONTINENT dropdown select]
[image: API call is returned from a getter method - Call is triggered for each & every CONTINENT dropdown select]

and

**if I remove the `.pipe(publishReplay(), refCount())` & run the code - both the instances behave in the same manner by *providing duplicate API calls - for each and every CONTINENT dropdown select***

[image: Duplicate calls on .pipe(publishReplay(), refCount()) removal]
[image: Duplicate calls on .pipe(publishReplay(), refCount()) removal]

**Why is the behavior like this for all these cases?**

Comment: The getter will be run on every change detection cycle, so you'll get a new instance and the share replay doesn't matter.

Comment: Which is the optimal approach here? the `getterMethod()` or the `property$`?

Comment: the getter return you a new cold observable every time, while the property is the same observable

Comment: You should use the `property$`, since it is a actual hot observable. So it won't make a http call everytime it gets subscribed to. BTW: `publishReplay()` is deprecated. Use `shareReplay` instead. Then you can also remove the  `refCount` I think.